# How do I write a question for an answer that teaches pros/cons/benefits/contexts?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

From `npm update`'s documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-update#description):

> Note that by default `npm update` will not update the semver values of direct dependencies in your project `package.json`, if you want to also update values in `package.json` you can run: `npm update --save` (or add the `save=true` option to a configuration file to make that the default behavior).

I can't think of any scenario where `npm update` should be used instead of `npm update --save`.

How do I write a question for an answer that teaches me the pros/cons/benefits/contexts?

Comment: I applaud you for asking before posting but I suspect it's not possible to do what you want. It seems massively over-broad a question to me. SO does not teach, we answer scoped answerable questions and this does not seem to that. Just my 2c.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've completely made this up, but let's say this were a valid answer to my meta question: "If you happen to be inside a node project and your goal is to update your *global* dependencies, you would want to use `npm update` because `npm update --save` would update your *local* dependencies instead." Again, I totally made that up, but if that were a valid answer, the question *seems* to be scoped and answerable, no?

Comment: But that is a *specific* instance, not the broad question you want to ask which would probably take up a whole chapter in a book.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think I understand. Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: "What are the use cases for using `npm update` over `npm update --save`?" seems like a reasonable, scoped, answerable, not opinion-based question, as long as the body of the question insisted on facts and experience over opinion. Whether it's of "pragmatic" use in software development is not a question I will go into...

Comment: @HereticMonkey That works for me. I intended to imply your wording anyway.

Comment: Please don't give a dubious title & then meta comment that it is dubious or that your post is not clear. Don't tell us that you are about to ask a question, just ask it. Edit your post including the title to say what you mean in the best presentation you can without referencing what it used to look like or adventures in editing. Ask 1 question. Not multiple questions. Please avoid emphatic fonts, especially large blocks. Anyway it is a sign of an unclear post. If this post needed the question in bold, every post would. Emphasis does not make unclear writing clear. **Yelling doesn't clarify.**

Comment: If you want more feedback: Scare quotes don't clarify the idiosyncratic meaning you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. Credit quoted content in always-visible text. Avoid rhetorical questions, they get confused with the post question. 'good' says nothing. PS Compare my edited versions to your original. Draft draft pause draft draft repeat. Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question with all & only necessary context. My edit removed more than usual. (But unfortunately it's frequently a lot). If this doesn't ask what you want, try editing your original & also my version.

Comment: @philipxy Your edit was almost perfect, but I needed to negate the second to last paragraph and did so a few seconds before your comment. Thanks, and thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yeah I saw they crossed. Re that recent edit: The original gave 3 phrasings of the same thing & I tried to keep one of them. What I kept was preceded by "what I'm trying to get out of my question", which I took to introduce what you wanted your question post to ask, but apparently was what you wanted an answer post "got out of your question" post to say. This is a good argument for not saying the same thing 3 ways & just asking for what you want instead of wrapping things in a bunch of meta commentary.

Comment: PS You don't connect your question clearly to the rest of your post preceding it. You seem to give an example consisting of a quote plus your reaction to it. No version has clearly expressed just what your example is a case of & just what it has to do with the question you want to ask. "(for example) `npm update` vs `npm update --save`" begged the question. Read your post versions & see what they actually say. When I edited I wasn't interested in extending to that for you but just in clarifying what you had already written, but I commented for you to please edit for clarity. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy `asking for what you want instead of wrapping things in a bunch of meta commentary` This, too, is a reaction to previous feedback. Usually when I tried to take your advice, I'm asked to share the context; you're helping me see why this reaction isn't productive, but I thought it might be useful to share the reason behind my behavior. `This is a good argument for not saying the same thing 3 ways` Yeah, that wasn't a conscious decision on my part. IME, past a certain point of self-editing, you start to lose the forest through the trees. I'll try to work on this, too.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that we have already asked and answered (according to my understanding of the link; I haven't used Node in forever):

> Q. What happens if I run `npm update`?
> A. The listed packages are updated to the latest version that satisfies the existing constraints.
> Q. What happens if I run `npm update --save`?
> A. The packages are updated as above, and `package.json` is also updated to reflect which versions were installed.

And now you want to ask:

> Q. Why should I run `npm update` instead of running `npm update --save`?

To the extent that there is any possible objective answer to that, it could **only possibly** look like:

> A. Because you want to update the dependencies, but don't want `package.json` to change.

If you couldn't come to a conclusion along those lines - assuming that I understood it properly! - then perhaps there is a meaningful question to ask. That is to say, you found the documentation page but didn't *understand* what it was telling you. In this case, the question is something like: "What is the practical effect of the `--save` flag for `npm update`?".

If your *real* question is "why would I not want `package.json` to change?", then that is just **purely speculative**, and thus *cannot be made* into a suitable Stack Overflow question. We could posit any number of workflows where the change would be either useful or counterproductive. Trying to enumerate those situations, or their motivations etc., is a fool's errand. We don't do "list" questions, especially not when it isn't clear how to decide whether two possible list items are actually distinct.

If you're "asking" it because you just find it *strange* that someone else might want those semantics, and haven't *yet personally encountered* a situation where you'd want it to work that way - then you **don't actually have a question**; you're just expressing skepticism of someone else's design decision. The phrasing "I can't think of a reason" makes it come across like this is your thought process. That is, if you're just trying to understand why *someone else* wants the functionality, then you *have not found "a practical, answerable problem" to solve*, and therefore *don't have the basis for a suitable question*.

Keep in mind, there could be someone else out there in the world who read the same documentation, coming from a different place, and wondered - in much the same way - "gee, why would I ever want the `package.json` to update here? Of *course* it should stay as it was, I'm only updating dependencies!".

To make it more obvious: imagine if we were trying to phrase such a question about, say, a programming language (as opposed to other programming languages that are commonly used for similar tasks). Obviously, both languages exist for a reason; obviously there *are* good reasons to use both - or else you'd never have heard of one of them, since nobody would talk about the obviously inferior option in any practical context. But **the problem is not simply with phrasing**; the subject matter is fundamentally unsuitable. Any question you could ask about it is either self-answering or based on personal preference. It can't be "asked objectively" because there isn't anything objective about it that has value to ask.

Comment: "*there could be someone else out there in the world*" hi, that would be me. The `--save` option only really makes sense to me if I've already updated the dependencies and seen that they work with the latest versions then I want to reflect this update in the project going forward.

Comment: @VLAZ that's matter of whether or not you decide to commit those changes or reset and reinstall, surely? Choosing not to `--save` is more like you're publishing a library and want to continue explicitly supporting earlier versions of the transitive dependencies too (lockfile-only changes wouldn't end up in the published package at all).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can imagine that it would have some use in CI for some elaborate use case. It's always good to have dry running options in any case - and be aware they are available.

Comment: @Gimby it's not a dry run, and it will edit the lockfile if there are any dependency changes - the `--save` flag only impacts whether the _package_ file is also changed.